# Why isn't my simple socket.io event system working?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am running into a problem while using socket.io to do some event handling. For some reason, the following code snippet does not handle the event 'update', or any event for that matter. Let me explain the situation.

I have created a file named updates.js to create a socket.io socket variable named socket_8888 that is bound to port 8888. I then use module.exports to make that socket variable available to any other file that imports updates.js using require('updates.js'). I structured my application this way because I need to emit events from several different files.

In app.js:

```
var updates = require('updates.js');

setTimeout(function() {

  updates.regular.on("update", function () {
    console.log("Updated.");
  })

}, 1000);

setTimeout(
  function () {

    console.log(updates.regular.eventNames()); // Verifying that there is actually a listener bound to the socket -> prints ['update']

    updates.regular.emit("update", 100)


  }, 1500);
```

In updates.js:

```
var io = require("socket.io");
var socket_8888 = io(8888);

var updates = {
    regular: socket_8888
};

module.exports = updates;
```

However, a few simple tests have uncovered that events are not being handled, and I really cannot figure out why. The word "Updated" should print a second and a half after I run the application using "node www", but it does not.

The reason I started doing this simple testing was because I am trying to revive an old website of mine, but after a couple years, API updates have rendered a lot of my code useless. So I am trying to rebuild. I am not trying to send events between different files on the server. I am only testing the events locally because the events were not firing to the browser client. For this reason, I decided to investigate using this simple test, and it turns out the events can not even be emitted/listened to on the actual server, let alone be handled on a client that is on a whole different network.

I have already verified that the listener is actually binding to the socket. However, I do not know how to check whether or not the socket is actually emitting the event "update".

I have written the listener to bind only after one second because attempting to bind the moment the application starts does not give Express enough time to set everything up. Otherwise, the socket would still be undefined.

I do not get any error messages. The code just does not work as I expected.

I would really appreciate it if the community can tell me why the event 'update' is not being handled.

Answer (score 0):

To include update module (update.js)

**Try this**

It work's Perfectly

```js
module.exports = updates
var  updates = require('./updates');
```

Comment: Are you saying I incorrectly imported my updates module into app.js? I verified that this is is not the problem. I am able to access the socket from app.js; events just never get handled for some reason. In any case, I tried to apply your solution, yet the events still do not get handled. Also the require('updates.js') statement that I included is not actually what is in in my file; the file path actually points to a different folder but I changed the file path for StackOverflow post purposes.

Comment: Are you saying that your client socket.io can not be handled ?